# silverlight content set more than once

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:dataInput="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data.Input" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Class="OrgChart.MainPage" mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="500" Width="1264">
   <ScrollViewer x:Name="MyScoller" Background="White" Margin="0,0,-102,28">
      <Canvas Canvas.Left="-30" Canvas.Top="-70" Height="100" Name="MyCanvas" Width="260" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
   </ScrollViewer>
   <TextBox Height="23" Name="ara" Canvas.Left="59" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Canvas.Top="-106" Width="120" />
</UserControl>
```

It shows set more than once error when I add textbox. If I add textbox into canvas, it doesn't give error. But I want to add outside of canvas. How can I handle on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Silverlight` you have two main classes of elements: `Controls` and `Panels`.

A Control can have only one child element (UserControl is a Control).

A Panel can have any number of child elements (Grid, StackPanel, Canvas are Panels).

If you want to place a TextBox below your ScrollViewer you can place them both inside a StackPanel:

```
<UserControl>
  <StackPanel>
    <ScrollViewer .../>
    <TextBox .../>
  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Martin, I solved problem now as adding stackpanel